# setTimeout does not execute lib on angular component 4

Tags: angular, video.js

setTimeout does not execute lib on angular component 4

I made two attempts, first using setTimeout and another observable

The script runs only once, then when you change the navigation to another component and back, the lib does not load anymore.

Observable

```
Observable.interval(500)
                .subscribe(i => {
                    this.player = videojs('player')
                })
```

setTimeout

```
setTimeout(() => {
                    $(function () {
                        this.player = videojs('player')
                    });
                }, 500);
```

Comment: You need to read about DOMContentLoaded event and arrow functions.

Comment: setTimeout(() => {
                this.player = videojs('player')
        }, 800);   Does not work.

Answer (score 0):

If this is Angular 2/4 try the following. Instead of relying on setTimeout or Observable.interval it's better to use built-in lifecycle hooks to do that. Here I suggest to use AfterViewInit hook.

```
class MyComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.player = videojs('player');
  }
}
```

This is example from official Angular 4 doc. I don't know your component name that's why I left default one from doc. Here is the link to the documentation: https://angular.io/api/core/AfterViewInit